# Does Steven Milloy hold the degrees he claims?

Tags: united-states, education

Steven Milloy describes himself on Twitter [@JunkScience](https://twitter.com/JunkScience) as

> Author, 'Scare Pollution: Why and How to Fix the EPA.' Trump EPA transition team. Statistician. Fmr SEC atty, mutual fund mgr, coal exec, & FOXNews columnist.

On the [About page of his JunkScience web-site](https://junkscience.com/about/), it claims:

> Milloy holds:
>
> - B.A. in Natural Sciences, Johns Hopkins University;
> - Master of Health Sciences (Biostatistics), Johns Hopkins University School of Hygiene and Public Health;
> - Juris Doctorate, University of Baltimore; and
> - Master of Laws (Securities regulation) from the Georgetown University Law Center.

His [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Steven_Milloy&oldid=799895703#Educational_background) uses some odd distancing language, saying "Milloy *claims* to hold" these degrees.

Does Steven Milloy hold these degrees?

Comment: I am not too familiar with this particular SE site, so: why the downvote? Is there something I should improve in my question?

Comment: When lazy Wikipedia contributors don't want to cite something, they'll just say it's claimed by someone. It's just lazy authorship, not skepticism.

Comment: Is there anybody actually claiming he doesn't, besides a wishy-washy wikipedia editor?

Comment: I don't think there's a notable claim he holds these degrees, or a notable claim that he doesn't hold these degrees.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The degrees from Johns Hopkins appear to be consistent with university records.

The JHU library [archives its past commencement programs](https://jscholarship.library.jhu.edu/handle/1774.2/36448/browse?type=title).  On page 25 of the [1981 commencement program](https://jscholarship.library.jhu.edu/handle/1774.2/36808), under "Bachelors of Arts in The School of Arts and Sciences", is an entry for "Steven J. Milloy, of Oxon Hill, Md."

On page 52 of the [1983 program](https://jscholarship.library.jhu.edu/handle/1774.2/36810), under "Masters of Health Science in The School of Hygiene and Public Health", is an entry for "Steven J. Milloy, of Fort Washington, Md.; B.A. The Johns Hopkins University, 1981. Biostatistics."

I haven't found similar records from the University of Baltimore or Georgetown, so I can't confirm or refute those.